# Accessing Another .NET Applications Controls

Tags: c#, .net, controls, ipc

Is it possible to have two seperate .NET Applications and be able to access their controls?

Example:

Program A has a `private RichTextBoxEx ConsoleBox;`

I would like to be able to hook that ConsoleBox with Program B, to be able to read the data inside it, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using 2 simple Windows API: the **FindWindowEx** & **SendMessage**

Check that simple article that I wrote long time ago but still valid though.

***Using Windows APIs from C#, again!***

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14519/Using-Windows-APIs-from-C-again

Comment: I would like to be able to use these natively, such as:
'OtherProgram.FormMain.ConsoleBox.Write();' not via the WinAPI. Is this possible?

Comment: @Smarter: Windows APIs are native APIs for windows. IMHO this is the simplest method for inter-process communication.

Comment: I am looking to interact with the objects natively as shown in my example.

Comment: @Smarter: I'm afraid that there is nothing I'm aware of in NET can offer what you're looking for :(